# NULL value inserted for previous value in boolean column in mysql

Tags: mysql, null, boolean, alter

I've added one new column to MySQL table as following:

```sql
alter table result add column failed boolean default 0;
```

This works fine though previous records in the table got NULL value in the failed field. I'm not sure how is this possible if field data type is boolean and also default set to 0.

can someone help

Comment: There is no boolean datatype in mysql

Comment: I believe MySQL automatically takes care of this data type, converting into tinyint.

Comment: Also I found that this behavior was seen in MariaDB but not on MySQL server. Also as per the MariaDB doc,
"The value of the new Column for every existing row of the Table is set to its default value"

So I think this datatype conversion is not correctly taken place in MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

It is set to null because you inserted those rows before adding the column, the default value is only for new inserts. You can update all values in the result table where failed is null and set it to 0 to work around the problem.

```
UPDATE result SET failed = 0 WHERE failed = null;
```

Comment: Do I always need to do this update after the column creation or at the time of creation only, can take care of this?

Comment: As diiN______ explained, if you set the column to be added to NOT NULL, it will use the default instead of null for existing rows

Comment: Also I found that this behavior was seen in MariaDB but not on MySQL server. Also as per the MariaDB doc, "The value of the new Column for every existing row of the Table is set to its default value". I checked the syntax for MariaDB and could see the difference:

alter table result add column failed boolean **set** default 0;

Answer (score 0):

That's how to use it

```
ALTER boolColumn SET DEFAULT 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your existing data doesn't get the default value, is because you are adding the column as `NULL`. That means only new data will get the default value. If you want to set the default value for the existing data, you should have added the column with `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE result
ADD COLUMN failed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```